Animated series featuring a white boy whose hair was flaming and a blue Caribbean female as part of a fighting team against evil forces
Trying to find out the title of a cartoon I saw on TV in 1999 or 2000.
It had a white boy whose hair was flaming and a blue Caribbean female as part of a fighting team against some evil forces. Also, some of the team members may have been animals.
Might be considered an animated series.

Like, his hair was on fire? Just very red? Stylish? Do you remember what sort of evil forces he fought? Robots? Aliens? Monsters? Demons? Corporate lawyers? What channels did you watch back then? Might it be something on Cartoon Network? A regional channel?

Blue as in blue skin? Like a smurf?

Gormiti? https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=pf5sGruzjSM they also did a reboot - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=TOQNtdnH2bQ
